# SVG action works with jsfiddle not in browser / localhost (SVG)

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create a hover effect on my SVG file even when my mouse is in the transparent parts of the SVG. As of right now the action is only activated when hovering the shape. I have tried

```
pointer-events: bounding-box;
```

without any luck (php storm doesn't even recognise the value) also tried the value *all* and the others. The weird thing is that it works in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elifro/jtb3bc15/3/) But not in localhost.

Been googling like crazy, hope someone have a solution for this!

Answer (score 0):

Just set `pointer-events: none` on the SVG and do the hover test on a parent `<div>`.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

div:hover svg circle {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="200px" height="200px" pointer-events="none">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="95" fill="red"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```